# How to block zero byte lock file (An object of Class InputStream)?

Tags: java, locking, inputstream

I have a code as shown and it works successfully. However, on including the commented line       `lock =f.tryLock()` it throws IOException. This is because of the lock on the file. I dont want the lock files to be read/copied (I need to filter lockfiles from InputStream) and thereby the code should not throw IOException in this case. Can somebody help me on this ?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;


public class Lock {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    RandomAccessFile file = null; // The file we'll lock
    FileChannel f = null; // The channel to the file
    FileLock lock = null; // The lock object we hold
    OutputStream out = null;
    InputStream in = null;

    try { 
      String tmpdir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
      String filename = Lock.class.getName() + ".lock";
      File lockfile = new File(tmpdir, filename);

      file = new RandomAccessFile(lockfile, "rw");
      f = file.getChannel();
     // lock = f.tryLock();
      in = new FileInputStream(lockfile);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      if(in.read(buffer)!=0){  
      int len = in.read(buffer);
      while (len != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        len = in.read(buffer); }
        }

      in.close();
      if (lock != null) {
        lockfile.deleteOnExit(); // Just a temporary file
      }

     } catch (IOException e) {    
        System.out.println(e);
        throw e;          
        }  
        finally{
        if (lock != null && lock.isValid())
        lock.release();
        if (file != null)
        file.close(); 
        }

  }
}
```

The exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:198)
at Lock.main(Lock.java:32)
```

Comment: What you mean by 'stop zero byte lock files from performing the above action'? And what IOException is thrown? And why are you copying lock files?

Comment: Impossible to reproduce: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/7f16c83e906a1f634de0 doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: And are you talking about lock files or locked files?

Comment: @EJP I am trying to stop the copy of locked files. The Exception raised is File Missing

Comment: @JBNizet The issue can be reproduced. Try creating a file as shown here and read from it [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/DemonstratesfilelockingandsimplefilereadandwriteoperationsusingjavaniochannelsFileChannel.htm)

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'File Missing' exception. At least I've  never seen one in 17 years.  Please post the full stack trace. And please explain why catching that exception, whatever it really is, doesn't completely solve your problem. And explain why the code in your link bears no relationship to the code you've posted here.

Comment: @EJB java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @Nimish I repeat. 1. Please post the full stack trace. 2. Please clarify whether you are  talking about 'zero byte lock files' or *locked* files. 3. Please explain why catching that exception doesn't completely solve your problem. And 4. Please explain how you got a FileNotFoundException on a file that was already open, in your original code. Your question does not make sense.

Comment: @EJP I am talking about file that have been locked.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified        
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.io.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:198)     
        at Lock.main(Lock.java:32)

Comment: My code needs to throw the IOException, But I need an idea to catch the IOException thrown because of this locked file.

Comment: So what does 'zero byte lock file' have to do with it? And why are you reading data and throwing it away? Three separate times? And, again, why is this a problem in the first place? If you can't read a file, for *any* reason, you can't copy it. So, if you get an IOException when copying, just close everything and delete the target file: it's invalid, incomplete, or empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reliably getting an IOException of some kind when reading locked files, merely catching it and aborting/cleaning up the copy appears to completely solve your problem. You have to do that anyway on any IOException, not just this one, so there's nothing special about this situation.

InputStream.available() doesn't have anything to do with either file locks or file sizes. See the Javadoc.

Comment: I have edited the question with a better snippet. Thanks for that comment